# How do I find out the super projects of a git submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

After a changing in a git submodule a manual searching is necessary to find out the main projects that track it. So, is there any way to know which remote super repos it is linked?

Comment: No. A git repository has no awareness of any projects using it as a submodule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way.  The main repo save references to submodules on .submodules files, but the submodules has NO references to parent repo. So, there is no way